# Хеш в адресе веб страниц и навигация

Tags: .htaccess

Подскажите пожалуйста как, и возможно ли переписать с помощью .htaccess вот такой адрес

```
index.php#test1
```

В вот такой `/test1`

Например вот так переписывается с `index.php` в просто `index`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Даже так можно

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index$ /index.php?param=123 [NC,L]
```

Но вот так не хочет

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index$ /index.php#test1 [NC,L]
```

Читал что можно вот так

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index$ /index.php%23test1 [NC,L]
```

В место хеша ставить %23 так как # в файле .htaccess это комент.
Но в таком случае ответ сервера таков

```
The requested URL /index.php3test1 was not found on this server.
```

Подскажите правильное решение, если оно существует. Или статейку какую интересную.

Comment: Поставьте флаг [`NE [No Escape]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) для `RewriteRule.`

Comment: В вообщем то работает. Но если сделать так

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^index$ /index.php#test1 [NE,R]

И ссылка будет такая 

    <a href="index">link</a>

То ссылка сработает, но почему URL все ровно не переписывается на index, а становится index.php#test1

Comment: а при каких условиях у вас в запрос попадает хэш ?

Comment: Просто делаю загрузку контента через jQuery, с помощью плагина hashchange и там подгрузка работает по хешу, по этому ссылки выходят такого вида <a href="#test1"></a> вот вообщем то ссылка на ресурс
http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/ ну а переходя по такой ссылки в URL отображается #test1 а хотелось бы убрать этот хеш что бы было хотя бы просто /test1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

плагин посмотрел... вся его суть в том чтобы делать #test1 в URL, запрос  к серверу выглядит так:

```
GET /code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/hashchange/ HTTP/1.1
Host: benalman.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1403.0 Safari/537.30
Referer: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/192344/htaccess-rewriterule-  %D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: UTF-8,*;q=0.5
```

Как вы можете убедиться серверу # не передается, 
есть другие  плагины поддерживающие history api с fallback.  например [вот этот](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) в случае с ними ваш rewriterule/роутер фреймворка должен учитывать, что иногда последний элемент в запросе "ненастоящий"

Comment: То есть мой выход поменять плагин, так вы хотите скозать, или я не правильно вас понял ?

Comment: Не совсем (хотя History.js всяко лучше hashchange), видимо вы не до конца понимаете что RewriteRule  переписывают  только серверные запросы. Если вы будете использовтаь History.js, то вам придется самим активировать элементы на странице используя js,  т.к. весь смысл hashchange именно в активации элемента страницы в зависимости от параметра #, в общем решать вам. Я ответил почему не получается и куда копать.

Comment: Блин думал все уже получилось но тут блин какая то мелочь все испортила, ну почему блин нельзя переписать этот долбанный хеш. Спасибо за содействие.

Comment: переписать то можно, но не будет работать (через history api, будет, но некроссбраузерно) - вы находитесь в ситуации "дудочка и кувшинчик", я настоятельно рекомендую таких ситуаций избегать во всех аспектах бытия.

Comment: Как же VK.com работает тогда ???? В плане Ajax подгрузки контента.

Comment: а в чем проблема с vk ? я давно у них не был, наверное history api используют, контент то нет проблемы грузить. все дело в устройстве приложения.

Answer (score 1):

Хэш и всё, что после него не передаётся серверу.
Содержание хэша ВКонтакте отслеживаются только с помощью JavaScript, и передаётся как GET-параметр в iFrame приложения, например. Изменения хэша так же отслеживаются JS, и вызывают, скажем, события во фрейме приложения.

Так что .htaccess здесь нерелевантен.

Comment: Общая схема такая: загружается страница, всегда одна и та же, и скрипт внутри неё смотрит, что там в хэше. И подгружает динамический контент. При переходе по ajax-ссылкам, меняет контент, и меняет хэш. Так получается имитация ссылок, и можно переходить "назад", "вперёд" и сохранять в закладках текущее состояние страницы.

Отдельно смотрите, как поисковики индексируют ajax-сайты. Например, [Яндекс пишет](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/?id=1125296).

Comment: Где в моём коментарии вы увидели хотя бы намёк на то, что "ajax сайт это полная хрень", или что они плохо индексируются?

Comment: надо просто ajax ссылки делать вида `<a href="/content">`, через ajax получать части страниц, а контроллеру приложения сказать, что если не ajax запрос, то генерировать страницу с нужным контентом. это убьет    сразу четырех зайцев - SEO, быстрая навигация, прямые переходы и поддержка браузеров с выключенным js.

Comment: Нашол один коменнт, если я не ошибаюсь то это и есть то что называется прямой переход по ссылкам для поисковика

    например у тэга a есть атрибут rel делаем что-то вроде <a   href="mysite.com/mypage/" rel="_ajax">Ajax link</a>
Потом получем все линки с rel="_ajax" и вешаем на них свои аякс функции, а поисковик этого не делает и идет напрямую по ссылкам…

Comment: http://doduts.comoj.com/ демку сделал :)

Comment: Ну да, ОЧЕНЬ даже не плохо. Я твой пример даже сохраню на Google Диск, уверен пригодится. Спасибо !!!